# What wolfram does to factor $x^6+x^2+2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I am learning polynomials and I am trying to understand what wolfram did to obtain $$(x^2+1)(x^4-x^2+2)$$ from $$x^6+x^2+2$$

It does not show me the step-by-step option in this case and I got confused. I only see $$x^2(x^4+1)+2$$ for this case.
Thank you.

Comment: Don't know about Wolfram, but by inspection $\pm i$ are roots. Another way is to let $t=x^2$, and note that $t^3+t+2$ has root $-1$.

Comment: Note that in your attempt, you didn't actually factor the polynomial, since you broke it into the *sum* rather than the *product* of two other polynomials.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Notice that $x^6+x^2+2=(x^6+1) + (x^2+1)$.
 Since $x^6+1$ is a sum of cubes it factors like this: $$x^6+1=(x^2+1)(x^4-x^2+1).$$ Putting these together gives $$x^6+x^2+2=(x^2+1)(x^4-x^2+1)+(x^2+1)=(x^2+1)(x^4-x^2+2).$$

Not sure about Wolfram's actual algorithm though. For algorithms see [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials). For an explanation of one algorithm that isn't too hard to follow, check out page 12 in 
Milne's [course notes](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf) on fields and Galois theory, it is remark 1.17.

Comment: Nice job (+1) :)

Answer (score 8):

You might substitute $x^2=u$ and look at the cubic $u^3+u+2=0$. Then a linear factor corresponds to a root, so we try the factors of $2$ and discover that $u=-1$ works. Thus, $u^3+u+2=(u+1)q(u)$ for some quadratic $q(u)$. Do synthetic division or long division to determine $q(u)$.